# How to swap hdd with m.2 drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a working PC with a normal hard drive connected (Drive c and some operating system partitions)
Now I purchased a new M.2 drive,
I would like to keep the installation and files currently on the the hard drive and move it all to the new M.2
How to do that? and how to set the M.2 drive as my C drive?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process can be different for every machine, but the basics are:

Boot up with both drives installed. Once you are in windows, install Macrium Reflect Free edition.

Confirm you can see both the HDD's in Explorer.

Read fully and understand the instructions for Macrium Reflect, as any data loss at this point will be your fault.

Open macrium reflect and do a clone (drive to drive) copy.

Once finished, switch off machine and remove old HDD. Keep safe.

Assuming you have the m2 slot enabled in the boot order, you should now be able to power on and boot from your new M2 drive.

Comment: @JohnyVegas Maybe it'll be better to reinstall the OS. I know it'll be a more tedious procces, but, many OS's like Windows, will change some internal parameters, depending on whether the OS is installed on an SSD, or an HDD. Cloning an installation of a OS from an HDD to a SSD may not get you the best configuration, and, even cause some minor issues.

Comment: Please let me know exactly what issues you think will be apparent when cloning. Apart from the samsung driver install there isn't anything else I can think of.

Best configuration / Minor issues - I really need to know.

Comment: @Johny I was refering to that driver you mentioned, and, if the OS doesn't detect that the drive has changed to a SSD, it may even try to defrag the disk (killing the SSD in the process if the original HDD was fragmented). Although it isn't likely for this to happen, it's always better to take prcautions. Maybe, my first comment was unclear, but I was refering that you have to know what you're doing when dealing with this. It is not that you _can't_ clone the OS, but, you may check that everything's ok when finished (The OS has detected the new hard drive type), and even, correct some things.

Comment: @Johny, that was successful,I was able to swap the drives, but after one night without the computer connected to power source im getting  
"Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device"  does the M.2 drive maintains data without power like normal hdd/ssd?

Comment: Sounds like your bios battery needs replacing. Get a cr2032 battery and replace it, then set your bios options and the boot order correctly - satam2 being the first.