# Will changing permissions on the "Users" or "Windows" folders be dangerous?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, permissions

I have a hard disk from a computer that won't turn on (the data is safe though), and I'm backing it up to an external drive. When copying certain folders (namely "Users" and "Windows"), I've been unable due to permissions restrictions. I've read up about the need to take ownership, but I'm worried that it will mess up system functionality if I plan to reuse the drive I'm backing up (which I am, because the data is fine). How safe is it to take ownership of these folders and change permissions *en masse* if I plan to reuse the drive as my boot drive in the other computer when repaired?

Comment: Is there any reason why you won't just reinstall Windows on the new machine? Potentially this could break various things. In addition, depending on how much your hardware changes, even without the permission change you might be unable to boot.

Comment: It is preferable to use a drive or partition copy: then the complete file system is copied, with the same names, short names, permissions and locations. A file-by-file copy won't necessarily produce a working system copy, because of changes in file properties.

Comment: @Seth There is no new machine. I'm backing up using the family computer, until I manage to repair my computer. The only thing I'm doing file-wise that isn't permission changes is copying files to my external drive, so I don't see how that would make me unable to boot.

Comment: @AFH How would I go about that?

Comment: There are lots of commercial and free packages to do this, some of which may have been bundled with, say, and external disc drive. Otherwise, search for "windows partition copy freeware" - I have been satisfied with [Mini-tool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/), which has a free edition. Earlier versions of Windows had a `backup` program which performed disc-to-disc copies.

Comment: @SUM1 As mentioned earlier, it's not recomended to copy a drive with Windows installed on it "file-by-file". Using this method you may miss hidden files, system files and the particion table of the disk (For a Windows installation is not as simple as one simple volume). What you should do is clone the disk, making a perfect copy of it. In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1335777/how-to-swap-hdd-with-m-2-drive) post it's explained how. If you're copying from and to the same disk type, there is no need to worry about the precautions in the comments of that post.

Comment: @milo8505 I don't have a clean spare hard drive to clone anything to. I planned to back the whole PC (under 1TB) up to a folder on one of my existing external drives, which had over 2.5TB free of 4TB. Is this still possible through other methods?

Comment: @SUM1 Yes, this is possible. Using a particion manager (The Windows one is good enough), you can reduce the 4TB volume by 1TB. The disk space you reduced will convert into unallocated space. Then, you can clone the particion table of your computer's disk to that unallocated space, and then clone the partitions of your computer's disk to those new in the external disk. This proccescan be done, but it may be more difficult and dangerous that a simple clone. If you do it, be very careful to not accidentally delete all your files in the external drive. **I recomend you backing that data up**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer my own question for others. Yes, it is dangerous, and it was probably what ended up corrupting my drive (specifically the master boot record) when I used it to boot into the fixed machine. Up until this point, I was a complete newbie when it came to dealing with individual computer parts, but in a matter of weeks I've come a long way and have managed to build myself a replacement computer from scratch.

Comment: I would be surprised if changing permissions and/or ownership would change the master boot record.   But I’m not shocked to hear that Windows gave you a hard time.   I hope you didn’t lose any data.

Comment: @Scott Yes, and to be honest I'm not entirely sure what did corrupt the drive, but it's the only thing I can think of that I messed around with before booting back into it (I changed several hundred permissions in the Windows folder before cancelling the operation). I managed to save all folders on the drive except what was in C:\Windows. However, reinstalling programmes on the new machine is proving to be absolute hell.

And I won't make the newbie mistake of copying folders anymore – I'm already imaging my new machine to external drives.

Answer (score 0):

For user profile folders, you shouldn't have to change the owner at all to get access. If you try to enter one that isn't yours while logged on as an administrator, Explorer will offer to adjust the access control list (ACL) to give you full access. If you accept, it will add access control entries that grant full control to the account you're using. These will not damage the rightful owner's ability to work with their files.

Who owns a file only matters when trying to change the ACL, so even if you take ownership of a system file, nothing terrible will happen. Various system folders, though, have special ACLs, and if you clobber their existing rules while giving yourself access, you could introduce security vulnerabilities or break the system. Fortunately, Explorer will warn you before automatically overwriting an ACL with one that gives you full control.

In short, you will be fine if you're careful, and even if not, permissions errors are correctable. Still, though, you can make your life easier by backing up the entire volume and then copying files out of that. [Disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) can create a virtual hard disk (VHD) file from one or more partitions. Assuming you have Windows 8 or newer, you can mount the resulting VHD by simply double-clicking it. (You might disconnect the original physical drive first so that you don't get them confused.) The virtual disk will have everything from the real disk, including the original permissions. You can steamroll the owner and/or ACL of any file on the virtual drive and grab your data.

Comment: It did not do what you said. It would prompt me, saying "You do not have permission", then even if I clicked "Continue", it would not allow me access. Many other people experienced this behaviour with internal drives. I don't feel like I'm in a position to do disk partitioning though. As milo8505 suggested, I'd need to backup my backup drives, which is not possible for me as I don't have that many drives. I've stuck with copying folders for now, as it's unlikely my broken computer's drive will get fried to the point of needing a reinstall.

Comment: @SUM1 Interesting. What OS are you using (both on the offline disk and the live machine)? Just to be clear, you got that error when trying to enter a user profile folder? For what it's worth, Disk2vhd doesn't require another physical drive or any repartitioning - it just makes a copy of a volume and saves it as a virtual hard disk file. All you need to do is choose where to save the VHD, check the volumes you want to include, and click Create.

Comment: The broken computer is Windows 7 64-bit, and the live machine is Windows 10 64-bit. Yes, I got the error when trying to either enter or copy both the "Users" and "Windows" folders. And thank you for suggesting that tool.